# Constant Interpolation in my animation not working

Tags: animation, keyframes, interpolation

The pose of my rig is changing on non keyframed frames even though I have the interpolation mode set to constant interpolation, which should only effect keyframed frames. The issue seems to only be happening with my rigged models, but if I create constant interpolation animation with a non rigged object it works just fine. Anyone know a solution to this?

I am willing to send the file if you think you can figure out a solution. I also have a video attached in the link that shows what is going on.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Cx_KQPCNrJTCV8ezKM4yO7nhqNQC5xyf/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi, impish, Blender _is_ a visualization and animation application, ... can you not use it to render out some frames for illustration, rather than shooting another display? Personally,  I'm having trouble seeing unwanted tweens in this shot. Please share a minimal example of your file that exhibits the problem on https://blend-exchange.com/, editing the link into your post.

Comment: Hello, impish, this question has been voted 'unclear', another illustration that would help us is a screen-grab of the graph-editor, showing us the f-curve of one of the channels that has the unwanted interpolation.